# Mysql error: violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous'

Tags: mysql, left-join, mysql-error-1052

I am getting the issue:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous

but the table `sales_flat_order_grid` have `created_at` **Column**

```
SELECT DISTINCT main_table.*, 
                blacklist.entity_id AS marked 
FROM   sales_flat_order_grid AS main_table 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT main_table.* 
                  FROM   plugincompany_blacklist_item AS main_table 
                  WHERE  ( order_id != '0' ) 
                  GROUP  BY order_id) AS blacklist 
              ON main_table.entity_id = blacklist.order_id 
WHERE  ( created_at >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00' 
         AND created_at <= '2016-11-26 23:59:59' )
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both tables have a created_at clause. So mysql does not know which one to take. You need to be clear about that:

```
WHERE  ( main_table.created_at >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00' 
     AND main_table.created_at <= '2016-11-26 23:59:59' )
```